# Regeln für Verwendung von Mir, Mich, Dir, Dich,

Tags: word-usage

Ich lerne Deutsch und habe Probleme mit dem Unterschied von mir, mich und dir, dich. Ich weiß nur mit Gefühl welches Wort ich verwenden muss und oft mache ich es falsch.

Zum Beispiel:

> Ich wasche **mir** die Hände.
>
> Ich unterhalte **mich** mit Anna.

Warum ist der erste Satz mit **mir** aber der zweite Satz mit **mich**? Wie kann ich das wissen? Gibt es Regeln dafür?

Oder noch ein Beispiel:

> Ich wasche **mir** die Hände.
>
> ABER:
>
> Ich wasche **mich**.

Warum nicht für beide Sätze mir oder mich? Warum unterschiedlich?

Ich wäre sehr dankbar wenn mir jemand helfen könnte.

Comment: Das sind Deklinationen. mir = Dativ. Frage: Wem oder was? mich = Akkusativ. Frage: Wen?. Bestimmte Verben kommen mit bestimmten Fällen. Waschen kommt mit Akkusativ (wen oder was wasche ich), SICH waschen ist ein reflexives Verb: Frage nach dem Fall: Wem oder was wasche ich die Hände: mir... Dir bleibt nichts, als das zusammen mit den Verben zu lernen.

Comment: What is your first language? - That's important to know; your language may or may not have similar syntactical constructs.

Answer (score 4):

> Ich wasche **mich**.

Das Wort *mich* ist das Ding, was gewaschen wird. *Ich*. Es handelt sich um das Akkusativobjekt des Verbs *waschen*.

> Ich wasche **die Hände**.

Jetzt wasche ich *die Hände*. Das ist ebenfalls das Akkusativobjekt des Verbs *waschen*. Es fehlt aber eine Information: Wessen Hände werden gewaschen?

> Ich wasche **meine Hände**.

Diese Variante benutzt das Possessivpronomen *mein* um zu erklären, *wessen* Hände gewaschen werden. *Meine*. Du kannst das so sagen und schreiben. Deutschsprecher bevorzugen allerdings die folgende Variante:

> Ich wasche *mir* **die Hände**.

Hier gibt es ein zusätzliches Dativobjekt *mir*. Es ist der *Empfänger* der Handwäsche. *Ich*.